# Spotlight is not searching for mp3 file in all directories in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, spotlight

I have to search mp3 files in all directories. I implement it using Spotlight, but it searches only in /user/userAccount/Music/Itunes Music. I have stored my songs on Desktop/Songs/*.mp3 and it doesn't search in this directory.

What should i do that my apps will search in all directories.

Comment: You didn't provide the full path to the file you're not finding via Spotlight. What's the path to the files on your Desktop? The user's files are located under /users/Desktop/... thus will be indexed by Spotlight (with the default settings), however Spotlight will not index every location on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

If Spotlight is not a requirement for you, you can use unix command [`find`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/popen.3.html). An example command line is:

```
find ~ -name '*.mp3'
```

provided that all your mp3 files have `.mp3` extention.

From a Cocoa app, you have to wrap it in a [`NSTask`](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or use a [`popen()`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/popen.3.html) call.